# Webpack 5 Html Webpack Plugin error "Error: Child compilation failed:"

Tags: javascript, webpack

After adding html-loader with file-loader to my Webpack configuration file I get an error bundling everything together.

I have an img tag in the template.html file.

It keep saying  *"Bad value for attribute "src" on element "img": Must   be non-empty"* but as you can see I do have value in the src attribute.

**Error**

Html Webpack Plugin:

```
  Error: Child compilation failed:
  Module Error (from ./node_modules/html-loader/dist/cjs.js):
  HtmlSourceError: Bad value for attribute "src" on element "img": Must   be non-empty (From line 78, column 17; to line 78, column 89)
  ModuleError: Module Error (from ./node_modules/html-loader/dist/cjs.js  ):
  HtmlSourceError: Bad value for attribute "src" on element "img": Must   be non-empty (From line 78, column 17; to line 78, column 89)
  
  - NormalModule.js:433 Object.emitError
    [PlaceFinder]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModule.js:433:6
  
  - index.js:61 Object.loader
    [PlaceFinder]/[html-loader]/dist/index.js:61:10
  
  - LoaderRunner.js:132 LOADER_EXECUTION
    [PlaceFinder]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:132:14
  
  - LoaderRunner.js:133 runSyncOrAsync
    [PlaceFinder]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:133:4
  
  - LoaderRunner.js:251 iterateNormalLoaders
    [PlaceFinder]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:251:2
  
  - LoaderRunner.js:224 Array.
    [PlaceFinder]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:224:4
  
  - CachedInputFileSystem.js:25 runCallbacks
    [PlaceFinder]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:25:15
  
  - CachedInputFileSystem.js:198 
    [PlaceFinder]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:198:4
  
  - graceful-fs.js:123 
    [PlaceFinder]/[graceful-fs]/graceful-fs.js:123:16
  
  - read_file_context.js:63 FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncompl    ete]
    internal/fs/read_file_context.js:63:3
  
  - child-compiler.js:159 
    [PlaceFinder]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/child-compiler.js:159:18
  
  - Compiler.js:511 
    [PlaceFinder]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:511:11
  
  - Compiler.js:1059 
    [PlaceFinder]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:1059:17
  
  
  - Hook.js:18 Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync]
    [PlaceFinder]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:18:14
  
  - Compiler.js:1055 
    [PlaceFinder]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:1055:33
  
  - Compilation.js:2119 
    [PlaceFinder]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:2119:10
  
  
  - Hook.js:18 Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync]
    [PlaceFinder]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:18:14
  
  - Compilation.js:2112 
    [PlaceFinder]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:2112:37
```

**My configuration file**

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const path = require("path");
module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  plugins: [new CleanWebpackPlugin(), new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: "./src/template.html",
    minify: false,
  })],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/i,
        use: [
          "style-loader", // Inject styles into DOM
          "css-loader", // Turns css into commonJS
          "sass-loader" // Turns sass into css
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/i,
        use: ["html-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(svg|png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: "[name].[ext]",
          outputhPath: "imgs"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

I can't find a way at the moment to solve this problem. Maybe someone here can help.

Comment: Is template.html the only html file in your codebase? html-loader is for bundling HTML files which can be imported to javascript modules. If the aim is just to generate an index.html which serves as the main page, only HTML-webpack-plugin is required.

Comment: @alexv yes template.html is the only html file. In my template.html I have  <img class="" src="./assets/logo.png" alt=""> which I want to generate it dynamically. I want Webpack to create a folder in the "dist" folder call "imgs" and inject the image code to the index.html file it creates. So as far as I know I need to use html-loader.

Comment: [this is what I want to do.](https://youtu.be/mnS_1lolc44?t=444) I follow this guide. He uses an older version of Webpack at that time.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. In the app I had an img src with no value.

To skip it remove the src from the image tag can help.

```
<img alt="" class="m-auto img-fluid" data-bind="attr: {src: img}">
```

The following configuration is now working in Webpack 5.

It will generate svg|png|jpe?g|gif into the dist folder with an hash file [name].[contenthash].[ext] and dynamically inject it into the code.

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const path = require("path");
module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  plugins: [new CleanWebpackPlugin(), new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: "./src/template.html",
    minify: false,
  })],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/i,
        use: [
          "style-loader", // Inject styles into DOM
          "css-loader", // Turns css into commonJS
          "sass-loader" // Turns sass into css
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html-loader',
        options: {
          minimize: {
            caseSensitive: true,
            conservativeCollapse: true,
            keepClosingSlash: true,
            minifyCSS: true,
            minifyJS: true,
            removeComments: false,
            collapseWhitespace: false,
            removeRedundantAttributes: true,
            removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
            removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(svg|png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: "[name].[contenthash].[ext]",
            outputhPath: "imgs"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```